# TYPO3 page permissions - Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

I've implemented code that is responsible for creating TYPO3 pages based on the data from the external source - code based mostly on Extbase.

How should I implement page permissions for each page? What is the best approach in this case? Should I extend my domain model (let's say class Page) to handle fields that are responsible for the permissions (like `perms_userid`, `perms_groupid`, `perms_user`, `perms_group`, `perms_everybody`)?

Answer (score 0):

For things like importing stuff from external sources I'd recommend to use the DataHandler instead of Extbase. Additionally Extbase does not provide a Page model by default which you need to implement first.

Take a look at the documentation for [DataHandler](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/UsingDataHandler/Index.html#tcemain-examples) and for the execution of your script use the [commands](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html).

Be aware to use the correct TYPO3 version of the documentations. My links lead to current master (main).

Comment: As I wrote: I already implemented Page model with the whole Extbase stuff for this. I understand that DataHandler is the best approach in general but in this specific case I would like to keep current convention for Extbase.

Comment: For someone who will have similar case: I've implemented a new extbase model for permissions and it works fine.